# How to check value is exist in ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>> in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert-update

First i insert the data when no records in database it works.
but when new data will come from server i want to check server record is exist in database or not for that i get all records from database and than i use hashmap loop for this if record is exist than update record otherwise insert new record

Here i put my code you can check it

```
String data=loadJSONFromAsset();
            Log.e("data","--->"+data);
            try 
            {   

                Open_Database();

                JSONObject jobject= new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jstore= jobject.getJSONArray(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.STORETERMINALINFO);

                myDBwifilist=mDB_Helper.GetAllRecord(mSQLiteDatabase,DB_Constant.TABLE.MYWIFI);
                Log.d("Record Count","----->"+myDBwifilist.size());

                // json array must > 0
                if(jstore.length()>0)
                {

                    for(int i=0;i<jstore.length();i++)
                    {

                        if(myDBwifilist.size()<=0)
                        {   
                                mDB_Helper.Insert_MYWIFI_Table(mSQLiteDatabase,
                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.WIFINAME),
                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID),
                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.STORE_ID),
                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LONGITUDE),
                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LATITUDE));
                        }
                        else
                        {   

                                for (HashMap<String, String> map : myDBwifilist) 
                                {
                                      for (String key : map.keySet()) 
                                      {
                                              if (key.equals(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.TERMINAL_ID)) 
                                              {
                                                     if(map.get(key).equals(jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID)))
                                                     {
                                                        int check=mDB_Helper.UpdateALLSSID(mSQLiteDatabase,
                                                                jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID),
                                                                jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.WIFINAME),
                                                                jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.STORE_ID),
                                                                jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LONGITUDE),
                                                                jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LATITUDE));
                                                         Log.d("Record Update", "----------> True"+check);
                                                     }
                                                     else
                                                     {
                                                         mDB_Helper.Insert_MYWIFI_Table(mSQLiteDatabase,
                                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.WIFINAME),
                                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID),
                                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.STORE_ID),
                                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LONGITUDE),
                                                                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LATITUDE));

                                                         Log.d("Record Update", "----------> false");
                                                     }
                                              }
                                       }
                                }

                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {


                }

                Close_Database();

            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

> // Get Records From Database

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> GetAllRecord(SQLiteDatabase db, String TableName) 
      {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<=0)
            {
                       cursor.close();
                        return data;
            }
            else
            {
                 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
                 {
                     do 
                     {
                         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                         map.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.WIFINAME, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.WIFINAME)));
                         map.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.TERMINAL_ID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.TERMINAL_ID)));
                         map.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.STORE_ID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.STORE_ID)));
                         map.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.LONGITUDE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.LONGITUDE)));
                         map.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.LATITUDE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.LATITUDE)));
                        data.add(map);

                     } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                 }
             }       
            cursor.close();
            return data;
      }

public int UpdateALLSSID(SQLiteDatabase db,String terminalid, 
                             String wifiname,
                             String storeid,
                             String longitude,
                             String latitude)
      {


          Log.e("terminalid","--->"+terminalid);

          ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
          cv.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.WIFINAME,wifiname); 
          cv.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.STORE_ID,storeid);
          cv.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.LONGITUDE,longitude);
          cv.put(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.LATITUDE,latitude);
          return db.update(DB_Constant.TABLE.MYWIFI, cv,DB_Constant.MYWIFI.TERMINAL_ID +" = "+terminalid, null);


      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

        boolean isNew=true;
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : myDBwifilist){
            if(map.get(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.TERMINAL_ID).equals(jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID)) && map.get(DB_Constant.MYWIFI.WIFINAME).equals(jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.WIFINAME))){
                isNew = false;
                break;
            }else{
                isNew = true;
            }
        }

        if(isNew){
            mDB_Helper.Insert_MYWIFI_Table(mSQLiteDatabase,
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.WIFINAME),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.STORE_ID),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LONGITUDE),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LATITUDE));

            Log.d("Record Update", "----------> false");
        }else{
            int check=mDB_Helper.UpdateALLSSID(mSQLiteDatabase,
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.TERMINAL_ID),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.WIFINAME),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.STORE_ID),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LONGITUDE),
                    jstore.getJSONObject(i).getString(WS_Constant.GETALLSSID.LATITUDE));
            Log.d("Record Update", "----------> True"+check);
        }
```

Comment: still got the problem is why is going to else condition duplicate record  will insert in this using else

Comment: i want to insert new record if it is not exist but in else condition is go if record is exist

Comment: Try to print both id.

Comment: current i check only terminal id it is possible to check terminal id and wifi name both are same than record is updte else insert new record ?

Comment: Now check ans i have edited with one more wifi name condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55839/discussion-between-haresh-and-android-tech).

Answer (score 0):

General example to check whether the value exists in `HashMap`

```
HashMap<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hMap.put("1", "One");
hMap.put("2", "Two");
hMap.put("3", "Three");

System.out.println(hMap.containsValue("Two"));  // the output will be true.
```

If it is true then update or else insert. Modify the code according to your need.